# mypy: Collection[str] replaces nested structure typing?

Tags: python, mypy

I have a `data` variable that, if typed properly, should look like this:

```
data: List[Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, List[Dict[str, str]]]]]] = []
```

But when I try to append to this list with the following code:

```
info = {"spaghetti": [{"value": "foo", "test": "bar"}]}
my_data = {
        "Name": name,
        "_info": info,
    }
data.append(my_data)
```

Mypy tells me:

```
Argument 1 to "append" of "list" has incompatible type "Dict[str, Collection[str]]"; expected "Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, List[Dict[str, str]]]]]"
```

Now, how is that possible that `Union[str, Dict[str, List[Dict[str, str]]]]` is equivalent to a `Collection[str]` ?

Comment: Note that `Dict[str, Any]` is a subset of `Collection[str]` because `dict`s implement the `Collection` interface.  Does it help to add a type annotation (or an explicit `cast`) to `info`?

Comment: It doesn't help to annotate `info`, but if I annotate `my_data` it does, no more warning.